# How can I translate the option in SELECT using i18N in VUE3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, i18next, vue-i18n

```
<n-select v-model:value="value" :options="options" />
      options: [
        {
          label: "Everybody",
          value: 'document',
        },
        {
          label: 'Drive My Car',
          value: 'class'
        }
]

value: ref('document),

en:
   class: Class
   document: Document
cn: 
   class : 类
   document: 文档
```

How can I translate the option in SELECT using i18N in VUE3

Looking forward to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to

```
import { t } from 'boot/i18n'
const { t, locale } = useI18n()
```

and then

in html template:

```
{{ $t('nameOfTextblock') }}
```

in your script

```
t('nameOfTextblock')
```

in the props

```
:propertyName="$t('nameOfTextblock')"
```

Comment: What if it's a select component
      options: [
        {
          label: "Everybody",
          value: 'document',
        },
        {
          label: 'Drive My Car',
          value: 'class'
        }    value is i18nt

Comment: in  {label: "Everybody", value: 'document', } you can translate "Everybody" and 'document' but why do you need to translate label or value? that is not displayed

options: [
        {
          label: t('text1'),
          value: t('text2'),
        },
        {
          label: t('text3'),
          value: t('text4'),
        }
]

en:
   text1: "Everybody"
   text2: "Document"
   text3: "Drive my car"
   text4: "class"